# Having a div with animated buttons appear on hover

Tags: css

A bit hard to describe in words, so I'll start off with an example:
http://www.hairstylesdesign.com/

I can achieve a similar effect where the dark background will appear when I set it's value from 0% opacity to 100% opacity..
example: 
.blackscreen { background:black; opacity: 0%; } 
.blackscreen:hover {opacity: 100%;}

But the problem is with the divs that are nested inside. Ex:

`<div class="picture">
    <div class="blackscreen">
        <div class="buttons">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

By making the opacity of the parent div equal to 0, it doesn't affect the divs nested inside. I'm wondering how this person managed to pull off that effect.

The help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried viewing their source / css in firebug to get a few ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opacity is not a value expressed in percentages and going from 0% to 100%, it is a fraction going from 0 to 1.

And it is one of the rare properties that can not be overriden by the cildren. If the parent has opacity 0, the child should always have opacity 0.